# How to Monitor IIS app pools and alert for any down time?

Tags: iis, iis-7, monitoring, application-pools

Does any one have any good ideas for monitoring `IIS 7` app pools for down time and either auto restarting them or alerting through email on them?

I found this [link](http://universitytechnology.blogspot.com/2008/11/powershell-monitor-iis-application-pool.html) with a nice power shell script but I don't know much about power shell scripting and would like it to monitor a list.

I'm looking to expand this script and read in pool names from a txt file and loop through them all every few minutes. That way I can simply modify the txt file to add or remove pools from monitoring. Or if any one knows of other either cheap or free tools to be able to do the same thing, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could setup an external monitor like pingdom (http://www.pingdom.com/) to watch the website and email you when the site goes down coz the app pool has stopped.